# Is the runner hit by the ball out or safe?

Tags: rules, baseball

Here is the situation we experienced in Little League baseball:

- The bases are loaded and the batter hits the ball down the third base line.
- All the base runners advance and score.
- But as the batter is reaching home plate, the outfielder throws the ball and it bounces off the ground and hits the batter in the leg.

They called the batter out. Why???

Comment: Ordinarily, the batter should *not* be out. The only reason to be called out here would be intentional interference.

Answer (score 0):

Runner should not be out unless there was some sort of interference. Maybe these will be helpful  in understanding what the umpire saw.

> Interference occurs any time a batting team acts in a way that impedes
>   the fielding team's attempt to play the ball. Section 2.00 of the
>   Official Rules describes different types of interference:
>
> INTERFERENCE (a) Offensive interference is an act by the team at bat
>   which interferes with, **obstructs, impedes, hinders or confuses** any
>   fielder attempting to make a play. If the umpire declares the batter,
>   batter-runner, or a runner out for interference, all other runners
>   shall return to the last base that was in the judgment of the umpire,
>   legally touched at the time of the interference, unless otherwise
>   provided by these rules. Rule 2.00 (Interference) Comment: In the
>   event the batter-runner has not reached first base, all runners shall
>   return to the base last occupied at the time of the pitch. (b)
>   Defensive interference is an act by a fielder which hinders or
>   prevents a batter from hitting a pitch. (c) Umpire's interference
>   occurs (1) When an umpire hinders, impedes or prevents a catcher's
>   throw attempting to prevent a stolen base, or (2) When a fair ball
>   touches an umpire on fair territory before passing a fielder. (d)
>   Spectator interference occurs when a spectator reaches out of the
>   stands, or goes on the playing field, and touches a live ball. On any
>   interference the ball is dead. The situation described under (b) is
>   known as catcher's interference. Interference is also explained in
>   detail in section 7.09 of the rules, in the chapter pertaining to the
>   runner. Penalties for interference are described in this section.
>
> A common case of interference occurs when a batted ball hits a
>   baserunner in fair territory. The ball is dead, the runner is
>   automatically out, the batter is credited with a single and other
>   baserunners only advance if forced to do so. If the ball hits the
>   runner in foul territory, it is simply a foul ball.

http://www.baseball-reference.com/bullpen/Interference

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. This answer comes from http://www.baseball-reference.com/bullpen/Interference. I blockquoted and added the source as this isn't your original work.

Answer (score -2):

Last answer is true.the only way a base runner would be out is if he or she is hit with the ball off the hitters bat

Comment: There are no other answers here, and your statement ("only ... if ...") is not correct: interference or leaving the line are most likely to be reasons here.

Answer (score -2):

The runner is not out if hit by ball of they running within the base path and thr opposing team was throwing the ball. If hower the ball os hit with the bat and the runner is hit with the ball then they are out.

Comment: A reference to rules that support your response, either implicitly by enumeration-exclusion or explicitly stating the same, would much improve this.